# Flink WindowAssigner assigns a window for every arrived element?

Tags: apache-flink

why `TumblingProcessingTimeWindows` assigns a window for every arrived element code as below?
For example, a TimeWindow with starttime of 1s and endtime 5s, then all elements between the time are expected to one window, but from the code below, every element gets a new window, why?

```java
public class TumblingProcessingTimeWindows extends WindowAssigner<Object, TimeWindow> {
    @Override
    public Collection<TimeWindow> assignWindows(Object element, long timestamp, WindowAssignerContext context) {
        final long now = context.getCurrentProcessingTime();
        long start = TimeWindow.getWindowStartWithOffset(now, offset, size);
        return Collections.singletonList(new TimeWindow(start, start + size));
    }
}
```

WindowOperator invoke `windowAssigner.assignWindows` for every element, why:

```
WindowOperator.java
    @Override
    public void processElement(StreamRecord<IN> element) throws Exception {
        final Collection<W> elementWindows = windowAssigner.assignWindows(
            element.getValue(), element.getTimestamp(), windowAssignerContext);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That's an artifact of how the implementation was done.

What ultimately matters is how a window's contents are stored in the state backend. Flink's state backends are organized around triples: (key, namespace, value). For a keyed time window, what gets stored is

- *key*: the key
- *namespace*: a copy of the time window (i.e., its class, start, and end)
- *value*: the list of elements assigned to this window pane

The `TimeWindow` object is just a convenient wrapper holding together the identifying information for each window. It's not a container used to store the elements being assigned to the window.

The code involved is pretty complex, but if you want to jump into the heart of it, you might take a look at `org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator#processElement`
(and also `EvictingWindowOperator#processElement`, which is very similar). Those methods use keyed state to store each incoming event in the window like this:

```java
windowState.setCurrentNamespace(stateWindow);
windowState.add(element.getValue());
```

where windowState is

```java
/** The state in which the window contents is stored. Each window is a namespace */
private transient InternalAppendingState<K, W, IN, ACC, ACC> windowState;
```

`InternalAppendingState` is a variant of `ListState` that exposes the namespace (which Flink's public APIs don't provide access to).

Comment: Thanks, but where can we find the process to apply a TimeWindow, SouceCode? where can we find that for events with event-time between [1s, 5s], WindowAssigner just apply just one TimeWIndow?

Comment: Or where can we find the datastructure in your anser?

Comment: I've expanded my answer to give some pointers -- but this is all rather too complex to thoroughly explain on SO.